# Mapboxgl is used to load data in B3DM format

Tags: 3d, mapbox, deck.gl

I uesd `@deck.gl` `maplibre-gl` `loaders.gl`, would load data in B3DM format. but ,  `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

I Can't find a reason. Please help me, thank you.

This is my code:

```
import maplibregl from "maplibre-gl";
import { Deck } from "@deck.gl/core";
import { Tile3DLayer } from "@deck.gl/geo-layers";
import { Tiles3DLoader } from "@loaders.gl/3d-tiles";

// map = new maplibregl ()
const dataUrl = "/static/blackJZ/tileset.json";
  const deck = new Deck({
    canvas: map.getContainer,
  });
const tile3DLayer = new Tile3DLayer({
  id:"dddd",
  loader:Tiles3DLoader,
  data:dataUrl,
  onTilesetLoad: tileset => {
    // Set the model matrix for each tile in the tileset
    tileset.traverse(tile => {
      tile.content._header.modelMatrix = tile.transform.matrix;
    });
  }
});
deck.setProps({layers: [tile3DLayer]});
// Add a listener to the mapboxgl.Map instance's resize event
deck.setProps({width: map.getCanvas().clientWidth, height: map.getCanvas().clientHeight});
```

this is B3DM link: [blackJZ-tileset](http://www.sxbych.com/b3dm-test/blackJZ.zip)